# Has_many through - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I’m a rails newbie here and have this issue.

I have 3 models: `Group`, `User`, `Subject`, between `Group` and `Subject` I have a `has_many` through relation called `GroupSubjects` it works fine, the next is `GroupUsers` with a `has_many` through relation and works fine too, as new at this (like 1 mint learning rails) I want to assign a subject, with another view, not the new or edit templates, and with this view, and make the relation between `Groups` and `Subjects`, I want to save the `user_id`, `group_id`, and `due date`, in the `GroupSubjects` table.

I really need help, this has been a problem for at least 3 days.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What have you tried? or at least explain a little more what you already have (since you say you don't want to use the new and edit views you must have thought another action name, and maybe something on the controller and a start of the form).

Comment: Maybe if you can update your question with the model code showing the relationships that may help give some more information on the solving the problem.  Can you also indicate how you are wanting to have in the user interface in order to get the correct relations setup.